# Вертикальное положение таблицы ng2-table angular2

Tags: angularjs

Подскажите, кто использовал модуль для ангуляра [ng2-table](http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/). Как сделать вертикальное положение таблицы, а не как, по дефолту - по горизонтали. Слишком много колонок и таблица уходит за поля страницы. 
 Думал, есть настройки какие-то. В документации не нашел, он генерирует структуру автоматически.

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под _вертикальное положение таблицы_?

Comment: Вот [ссылка](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_headers), смотрите 2ой вариант

Comment: да, в данном модуле это сделать невозможно, так как для заголовка он использует [секцию thead и она жестко забита](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table/blob/development/components/table/ng-table.component.ts#L9)

Comment: В теории можно попробовать наследоваться от этого компонента и сделать свой шаблон, но будет ли это работать на практике не знаю :)

Comment: @Grundy Идея, сейчас попробую, спасибо)

Comment: Если получится, напиши свой ответ с примером :-)